# Windows 8. Чего хочет рынок?

Tags: windows-8, controls

Появилось желание начать писать контролы для win8. Хочу узнать мнение многих на тему: что писать чтоб это можно было продавать? Например, есть что-то такое: http://www.telerik.com/developer-productivity-tools.aspx

Ребята пишут UI контролы. Вопрос: чего хочет рынок по Вашему мнению?

Comment: мое мнение - рынку windows8 не сильно нужна. Может следующая будет лучше.

Comment: Мелкософт делает хорошие системы через одну. 8ка в их число не входит, по крайней мере под стационарные компьютеры. Они хотят быть комбайнами-оркестрами под всё и вся, в то время как эппл доказал, что закрытая эко-система куда лучше своим софтом под своё железо и своим аппстором.

Comment: может быть вы в какой-то мере и правы, но не может быть такого, что нечто не будет продаваться. Хотелось бы понять чем может быть это нечто

Comment: берете Делфи, смотрите, какие были успешные компоненты. Дальше пишете свои аналоги, только для windows8. Profit.

Comment: Я купил и через месяц выкинул Win8 - откатился назад. Говно. Теперь по сути:

1) Метро дизайн придуман для тачскрина, но для другого (мышино-клавиатурного) он неудобен. Простой пример: если вы пальцем тыкаете в монитор - то монитор трясется от тычком - раздражает жутко. Для таблетки или телефона, который на коленях это неважно, но для десктопа это не то.

2) Еще мало истинно Win8 приложений (старые compatible не в счет)